# C# Dapper query using WHERE IN

Tags: c#, dapper

I am trying to perform a dapper query like this:

```
string query = "select * from MyTable where someNumber in @Nums;";
...
connection.Query<ReturnObj>(query, new {Nums = nums})
```

And I am getting a MySql syntax error if nums is empty. It looks like Dapper changes the query to look like this: `WHERE 1 = 0)` so I am guessing it the left ( is missing, which is causing the syntax error. Yes, I realize I could just check if the collection is empty before executing the query, but I would rather not if I don't have to.

Comment: nums = numIds.ToReadOnlyCollection(), where numIds is an IEnumerable

Comment: It's more rather the fact that I think Dapper should handle a situation like this rather than me having to fix it's mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [bug in Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/issues/565) where it creates a SQL statement that is invalid for MySQL Server 5.6 (and earlier).

Workarounds:

- Upgrade to MySQL Server 5.7 (which accepts the SQL Dapper generates and returns the expected results)
- As you said, check if the collection is empty before executing the query

A variant of checking if the collection is empty (that can be useful if you have a complex query, `NOT IN`, etc.):

```
  var numsSql = nums.Any() ? "@Nums" : "(select null)";
  var query = $"select * from MyTable where someNumber in {numsSql};";
  conn.Query(query, new { Nums });
```